# Validating and update entities in Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, updating

The title may not be as accurate, if someone finds a better one and can update it, please do so :)

I have a small CMS to edit users. 
I'm using Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2. 
I have a fieldset + form to add a user and (possibly) the same one to update them.

The User entity has the following fields:id, username, password, email.

The fieldset has two validators that check if the username and the email already exist. 
Since I'm using the same to update the users, when I change for example the username of the user and keep the email the same, it throws an error that the "email exists" (which is normal due to the validator) and the same when I change the username and keep the email etc.

What I want is to avoid that behavior and make it so it checks them only when they are really changed/updated.

I thought of some ways, but I'm not sure what the "best" approach would be to this.

- Hardcode the whole thing, by checking if the fields change and then do the validation (which makes the whole fieldset pretty much useless)
- Make a function in the User entity that accepts an array with the new values, then compares them to the old ones and passes the changed ones to a "validation" function that returns the errors (which is mostly like the previous way, but I guess a bit more structured)
- Write a validator and attach it to a new form which will query the db to check if the email/username exists and it's not already in use by the particular id, but I'm not quite sure on how to write it since I can't figure out how to pass the id and the field to the validator

I guess the 3rd one would be the best since it does 2 jobs at one time, by checking if the field changed and is not already in use by another user.

What do you suggest? How do you deal with that kind of scenario?

I can post any code that is needed, but I think this is more of a structural problem and that the code I used is too common and easy to figure out.

Comment: iirc the [`UniqueObject`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Validator/UniqueObject.php)-Validator is exactly what you'd need. [The Docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md) will also help.

Comment: As Said "Unique Object" or 3rd approach where as you have to extend new filter with your old filter, that is 1 way of passing ID.